# l() is printing "http://node/16" when gets "/node/16" as argument

Tags: 6, uri

This site was copied to a new domain when it started breaking. Is there some setting somewhere I need to update, so it knows how to build working URLs again?

Comment: did you try to clear the cache?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass *node/16*, instead of */node/16*.

The [API reference for l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6) tells you that the `$path` argument is passed to the [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/6) function. `url()` considers "/node/16" as a full URL (although the term "full URL" is not formally defined).

Comment: Huh you're right. I was using the node->path field. I changed to using node->nid and just concatenating node/ to it when I build the link.

Comment: the node->path shouldnt contain a leading slash either.